# Choosing a suitable design structural pattern for a use case

Tags: design-patterns, python

I have the following models.

First, there is a `Vector` which has a circular DNA sequence.
Second, there is a `LinearizedVector` which could one of below classes.

```
LinearizedVectorBase:  
  LinearizedVectorByOneCut   
     ConcreteLinearizedVectorByOnePosition  
     ConcreteLinearizedVectorByOneEnzyme  
     ConcreteLinearizedVectorByOneEnzymeOrPosition  
  ConcreteLinearizedVectorByTwoCuts is composed of two 
    `ConcreteLinearizedVectorByOneEnzymeOrPosition`
```

The base class `LinearizedVectorBase` has the following abstract methods:

```
linearize_vector()
get_feature_instances()
```

**The current design**

[image]

The problem with the current design is that `ConcreteLinearizedVectorByOneEnzymeOrPosition` has two parents with different implementations.

```py
class ConcreteLinearizedVectorByOneEnzymeOrPosition
   def get_feature_instances(self):
       if self.restriction_enzyme is not None:
            # it should be `ConcreteLinearizedVectorByOneEnzyme().get_feature_instances()`
            return ?
       elif self.cut_position is not None:
            # it should be `ConcreteLinearizedVectorByOnePosition().get_feature_instances()`
            return ?
```

I want to have two types of enzyme and position within one model so `ConcreteLinearizedVectorByTwoCuts` could have a composition relation of two objects of `ConcreteLinearizedVectorByOneEnzymeOrPosition`.   Otherwise, it will grow exponentially in the numbers of models, `ConcreteLinearizedVectorByTwoEnzymes`,`ConcreteLinearizedVectorByTwoPositions`,`ConcreteLinearizedVectorByEnzymeAndPosition`,`ConcreteLinearizedVectorByPositionAndEnzyme`, which is clearly wrong.

I'm trying to minimize the number of concrete classes that exist as a result of the possible permutation of Position and Enzymes. When I used a concrete EnzymeOrPosition class and used it in the LinearizedVectorByTwoCuts by a composition relation, I faced the issue of having two parents with a different implementation.

The flow of the program:

```py
linearized_vector = linearize_vector(vector, **kwargs)
feature_instances = linearized_vector.get_feature_instances()
```

What is a better way of designing this use case?

Comment: What is the problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: I see three things at work here:  "Linearized Vectors," "Positions," and "Enzymes."  I'm put-off by the fact that "One" vs. "Two" is embodied as distinct classes.  But I don't know the problem-space at all, having never been a biologist.  It feels to me, though, that there's one base class and several *attributes* having a 1:1 or at least 1:2 (maybe more than 2?) relationship.  Dunno... echoing what Bob just said... *"what is the problem you are trying to solve?"*

Comment: Thanks, I edited the question to include what I'm trying to solve.

Comment: You are not choosing a design patterns, but you write working code first and then refactor it to the pattern you recognised in your already written code.

Comment: @Fabio While I agree with your sentiment not to look for design patterns prematurely, there are problems where a particular design pattern's utility is obvious quite early on.  I think FadiBakoura had done enough coding/modeling to determine that his approach was untenable, and he had the wisdom and humility to identify a situation where a pattern might improve his design and ask for help.

Comment: @PhilipWrage, my point was simply that one of the approaches for OP's issue is just to start writing code with all possible `if .. elses` and then to recognise suitable pattern. In most of the cases OP will recognise pattern while writing code and can implement without waiting for "refactoring" stage. Especially when you are going to use inheritance. Inheritance introduces strong coupling, so I would suggest to use copy-paste before.

Comment: @Fabio, I wasn't having a go at you mate, and I apologize for giving that impression.  I agree with your points.  I just wanted to point out that sometimes a developer can intuitively identify "code smells" without having the knowledge or vocabulary of patterns that are appropriate and that can genuinely help them.  Cheers!

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. I've started learning design patterns just five days ago. And, now I will continue learning them because, as mentioned, I need to have the knowledge or vocabulary of patterns to use them when I see a code smell.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to linearize your plasmid with one or more restriction enzymes, positional cuts, some other mechanisms (for example, based on a Sequence that is independent of restriction enzyme), or any combination of these.

However, you don't want to have to create concrete classes for each one of these possible combinations - you'll end up with a combinatorial explosion and unmaintainable code.

I think the best way to handle your problem is to use the [Decorator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decorator_pattern).

First, define the `Component` (`LinearizedVector`) and `ConcreteComponent` (`ConcreteLinearizedVector`).

```py
class LinearizedVector():
    """
    Define the interface, or contract, of the LinearizedVector
    """
    def linearize_vector(self):
        pass

    def get_feature_instances(self):
        pass


class ConcreteLinearizedVector(LinearizedVector):
    """
    Basic concrete implementation of LinearizedVector that holds circular vector
    """
    _vector = None

    def __init__(self, vector):
        self._vector = vector

    def linearize_vector(self):
        return "ConcreteLinearizedVector.linearize_vector(" + self._vector + ")"

    def get_feature_instances(self):
        return "ConcreteLinearizedVector.get_feature_instances(" + self._vector + ")"
```

Next, define your `Decorator` (`LinearizedVectorDecorator`).  The `Decorator` will not only inherit from the `Component` class (`LinearizedVector`), it will also be composed of a `Component` class ('has-a' relationship), allowing the `Decorator` to 'wrap' an instance of the `Component`, or one of its children.

This permits the `Decorator` (and its `ConcreteDecorator` children) to be substituted anywhere in your client code where a `Component` (`LinearizedVector`) is expected.

The `Decorator` simply delegates calls to the methods it inherits from `Component` to the same methods on the `Component` that it wraps.

```py
class LinearizedVectorDecorator(LinearizedVector):
    """
    Decorator wraps and inherits from LinearizedVector.
    This way it can be used anywhere a LinearizedVector can be used,
    and it simply delegates operations to the component it wraps.
    This will be the base decorator that concrete decorator implementations inherit from.
    """
    _linearized_vector = None
    _cut_positions = []

    def __init__(self, linearized_vector):
        self._linearized_vector = linearized_vector

    def linearize_vector(self):
        """ 
        delegate to the method on wrapped LinearizedVector
        """
        return self._linearized_vector.linearize_vector()

    def get_feature_instances(self):
        """ 
        delegate to the method on wrapped LinearizedVector
        """
        return self._linearized_vector.get_feature_instances()

    def get_cut_positions(self):
        return self._cut_positions

    def set_cut_positions(self, cut_positions):
        self._cut_positions = cut_positions
```

Finally, define `ConcreteDecorator` classes (`RestrictionEnzymeLinearizedVectorDecorator`, `PositionallyLinearizedVectorDecorator`) that inherit from the `Decorator` (`LinearizedVectorDecorator`).

These `ConcreteDecorator` classes can now add state and/or behavior to the `Component`.  The `ConcreteDecorator` classes still delegate to the 'wrapped' `Component` instance, but by wrapping that `Component` they can now inject new behavior before and/or after the delegated method calls.

```py
class RestrictionEnzymeLinearizedVectorDecorator(LinearizedVectorDecorator):
    """
    Delegate to the wrapped LinearizedVector and alter method results
    with restriction enzyme cut specific behaviors.
    """

    _restriction_enzyme = None

    def __init__(self, linearized_vector, restriction_enzyme):
        super().__init__( linearized_vector )
        self._restriction_enzyme = restriction_enzyme

    def linearize_vector(self):
        return "RestrictionEnzymeLinearizedVectorDecorator[ enzyme: " + self._restriction_enzyme + ", " + super().linearize_vector() + "]"

    def get_feature_instances(self):
        return "RestrictionEnzymeLinearizedVectorDecorator[ enzyme: " + self._restriction_enzyme + ", " + super().get_feature_instances() + "]"


class PositionallyLinearizedVectorDecorator(LinearizedVectorDecorator):
    """
    Delegate to the wrapped LinearizedVector and alter method results
    with positionally cut specific behaviors.
    """

    _cut_position = None

    def __init__(self, linearized_vector, cut_position):
        super().__init__( linearized_vector )
        self._cut_position = cut_position
        self.set_cut_positions( self.get_cut_positions().append( cut_position ) )

    def linearize_vector(self):
        return "PositionallyLinearizedVectorDecorator[ pos: " + str(self._cut_position) + ", " + super().linearize_vector() + "]"

    def get_feature_instances(self):
        return "PositionallyLinearizedVectorDecorator[ pos: " + str(self._cut_position) + ", " + super().get_feature_instances() + "]"
```

Now, to use your new code, simply instantiate your `ConcreteComponent` and pass it to the constructor of one of your `ConcreteDecorator`s.  You can do this in separate steps, or all at one time.

You can also nest your `ConcreteDecorator`s multiple layers deep, but if you write them correctly, they will adhere to the base contract established by `Component`, and the added behavior will be transparent.

```py
vector = RestrictionEnzymeLinearizedVectorDecorator( RestrictionEnzymeLinearizedVectorDecorator( ConcreteLinearizedVector( "ATGCAGTTACCGTGAGAATTCTTAG" ), "BamHI" ), "EcoRI" )

vector.linearize_vector()

anotherVector = RestrictionEnzymeLinearizedVectorDecorator( PositionallyLinearizedVectorDecorator( ConcreteLinearizedVector( "ATGCAGTTACCGTGAGAATTCTTAG" ), 3 ), "EcoRI" )

anotherVector.linearize_vector()
```

Example Output:

```
'RestrictionEnzymeLinearizedVectorDecorator[ enzyme: EcoRI, RestrictionEnzymeLinearizedVectorDecorator[ enzyme: BamHI, ConcreteLinearizedVector.linearize_vector(ATGCAGTTACCGTGAGAATTCTTAG)]]'

'RestrictionEnzymeLinearizedVectorDecorator[ enzyme: EcoRI, PositionallyLinearizedVectorDecorator[ pos: 3, ConcreteLinearizedVector.linearize_vector(ATGCAGTTACCGTGAGAATTCTTAG)]]'
```